# How many registration IDs per device and and user does Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) issue?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-play, google-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing a GCM handler on my server. Does Google issue a new Registration ID per device or per user? I know they issue a new ID per App version and user, but does that extend to each device the user has the app installed on?

Ultimately, I ask because I want to know how I should store a Registration ID a user's app sends me server-side.

Right now I have it implemented such that the most recently sent ID is the user's only Registration ID, but I am unsure if this is an incorrect way to model how GCM handles registration IDs. I'm leaning towards it being incorrect and that I'd have to keep a record of many IDs based on some criteria.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, GCM issues a new registration ID per device with the app installed. To answer your question, 1 registration ID per device.

GCM does not know anything about your own users, so it is up to you to implement the logic of how to sift through messages intended for User X and Y, if both of them use the same device.

Here's something from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#register):

> A registration ID isn't associated with a particular logged in user. If you unregister and then re-register, GCM may return the same ID or a different ID—there's no guarantee either way.
> To make sure that messages go to the intended user:
>
> - Your app server can maintain a mapping between the current user and the registration ID.
> - The app can then check to ensure that messages it receives match the logged in user.

The whole "matching" concept in the last bullet is what I meant by sifting through.

Comment: may be important to also note that you can actually have multiple registration IDs per device, if the app registers more than once. You can reconcile this usings GCM's "canonical registration IDs" facility: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#reg

Comment: Thanks for adding that. For OP's information, the canonical registration ID is the ID that is included in GCM's response if somehow there are multiple registration IDs for a device and GCM wants you to stick to the canonical reg ID from then on.

Comment: Does it means that, for the same device, the Reg ID for a particular app will always be the same regardless of the app version and android version update? Means, for App1 ver 1.0 on Kitkat will generate same Reg ID for App1 ver 3.5 on Lollipop using the same device?

Answer (score 1):

It is issuing an ID that depends on both. If the user changes on a specific device, the ID will change and vice versa. Also a user can have more devices and on each device the ID differs. But you should know that google has a limitation of how many devices each user can have, last time I checked it was 10.

You should also be checking the result the GCM server returns, it will tell you if the ID is dead and you can remove it from your database.